# Send sms via usb 3g

Tags: java

*Hi all,*

I want to use usb 3G to send sms to a phone number every 30 minutes from a computer.

How could i do that? Please somebody help me.

Thanks very much !!!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [SMSLib](http://smslib.org/):

> SMSLib is a programmer's library for sending and receiving SMS
>   messages via a GSM modem or mobile phone. SMSLib also supports a few
>   bulk SMS operators.